# Reading date as a day before when reading excel file using xlsx package

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, datetime, xlsx

On the excel file I have a cell as  2000-12-01 as date(dob) amongst others. Upon reading the date with xlsx package, I have the date as 2000-11-30T22:59:25.000Z (1hr 0 min 35s difference). I can still accommodate the 1 hour time zone difference but the 35s difference is the big trouble I have as this takes the date to the previous date instead of the actual day. The person's birthday is 1st of December instead it reads 30th November. How do I fix this please?

```js
const readFile = xlsx.read(fileStored.Body, {
    cellDates: true
  });
  
 //retreived object looks thus
 [
  {
    dob: 2000-11-30T22:59:25.000Z,
    startDate: 2022-04-05T22:59:25.000Z,
    ... 
  }
]

console.log("date1", moment(rawDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").tz("UTC").format()); //date1 2000-11-30T22:59:25Z



console.log("date2", moment(rawDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")); //date2 Moment<2000-11-30T23:59:25+01:00>
```

The dob or other dates reads value of the previous day of the actual date.

Answer (score 1):

This seems too easy, but couldn't you just [setHours](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp) ahead by 2 (or more?) and all the lower metrics (minutes, seconds, milliseconds) to zero?

Something like....

```
//adds two hours to your date and sets min,secons, ms to 0.
dob.setHours(dob.getHours() + 2, 0, 0, 0); 

//sets date hour to be midnight.
dob.setHours(0); // set time
```